# Passing pytest function arguments to a fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am trying to create a fixure that simply prints the arguments of a pytest test case.

For example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def print_test_function_arguments(request):
    # Get the value of argument_1 from the run of the test function
    print(f'argument_1 = {value_1}')
    

def test_something(print_test_function_arguments, argument_1, argument_2):    
    assert False
```

Comment: So you want to print the fixtures used by a test? This can be done in `pytest_generate_tests` by accessing `metafunc.fixturenames`.

Comment: Is there a way to use in my fixtures the arguments that have been passed to test_something?

Comment: You are aware that arguments in tests are fixtures, right? What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to get access to the value of argument_1 inside print_test_function_arguments

Comment: Yes, I understood - my question is - why do you need a fixture to access the other fixtures, and can't do this in `pytest_generate_tests` as proposed? Obviously you want to do more than print the names, otherwise you could do that.

Comment: For example, I want to create a fixture where if the test fails, it will save somewhere the fixtures values for future inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do any kind of introspection, `request` fixture is the way to go. `request.node` gives you the current test item, `request.node.function` the `test_something` function object and `request.getfixturevalue("spam")` will evaluate the fixture `spam` and return its result (or take it from fixture cache if already evaluated before). A simple args introspection example (untested):

```
import inspect
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def print_test_function_arguments(request):
    argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(request.node.function)
    positional_args = argspec.args
    positional_args.remove("print_test_function_arguments")
    for argname in positional_args:
        print(argname, "=", request.getfixturevalue(argname))
```

Of course, you can't evaluate the fixture `print_test_function_arguments` in its body, otherwise it will stuck in an infinite recursion, so its name must be removed from arguments list first.